# Fresnel equations for perpendicular angle of entry

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

In many text books one finds for the fresnel coefficients for light perpendicular to the surface:
$$r = \dfrac{n_1 - n_2}{n_1 + n_2}\quad\text{and}
\quad t = \dfrac{2n_1}{n_1 + n_2}.$$

When I try to establish $t$ from $r$ with the relation that the overall intensity stays the same

$$R + T =r^2 + t^2 = 1.$$

I get

$$t = \dfrac{2\sqrt{n_1\cdot n_2}}{n_1 + n_2}.$$

How does this fit together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$r^2 + t^2 \neq 1$$

You have forgotten that the refractive index changes, the speed of light in the media changes and thus the intensity is not jut proportional to the square of the electric field intensity, it is proportional to $n E^2$. Thus
$$n_1 r^2 + n_2 t^2 = n_1$$
$$ t^2 = \left( \frac{n_1}{n_2}\right)(1 - r^2)$$
$$t =\frac{2n_1}{n_1+n_2}$$